# Django TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a connection form, but I get this error : TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

form :

```
from django import forms

class Connection(forms.Form):
    username_connection = forms.EmailField(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.EmailField(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    password_connection = forms.PasswordInput(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))

    first_name_signin   = forms.CharField(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    last_name_signin    = forms.CharField(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    artist_name_signin  = forms.CharField(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    email_signin        = forms.EmailField(label = None, widget = forms.EmailField(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    password1_signin    = forms.PasswordInput(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
    password2_signin    = forms.PasswordInput(label = None, max_length=80, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "modal-input-placement-homepage"}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using **EmailField** as widget. its wrong. change it with **EmailInput**